# Shortest distance in maze using depth first search

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

Given a MxN matrix where each element can either be 'o', 's' or 'g' (*'s' and 'g' are unique. Only one starting point and one ending point*).

Assume that starting cell 's' is always at (0,0).

We want to find the shortest distance between starting cell 's' to goal cell 'g', while avoiding obstacle 'o'.

Example:

```
['s', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', 'o', 'o', 'o']
['o', ' ', 'o', ' ', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'o', ' ']
[' ', ' ', ' ', 'g', ' ']
```

The shortest distance from 's' to 'g' is 7.

I understand that we can solve this easily using **breadth first search** or **hadlock algorithm**. However, I had a hard time trying to understand why my depth first search *wouldn't work*.

I'm writing in Python and my code is as follow.

```
class Solution:
   :type maze: list of list
   :type start: tuple
   :type end: tuple
   :rtype: int
   def findShortestDistance(self, maze, start, end):
      self.shortest=math.inf

      #set the default value of visited to be False
      self.visited=defaultdict(lambda: False)

      self.maze=maze
      self.rows=len(maze)
      self.cols=len(maze[0])
      self.depthFirstSearch(0,0,0)
      return self.shortest

   def depthFirstSearch(self, i, j, numStep):
      if i<0 or j<0 or i>=self.rows or j>=self.cols:
         return
      elif self.maze[i][j]=='o':
         return
      elif self.maze[i][j]=='g':
         self.shortest=min(self.shortest,numStep)
         return
      elif self.visited[(i,j)]:
         return

      self.visited[(i,j)]=True

      self.depthFirstSearch(i-1,j,numStep+1)
      self.depthFirstSearch(i,j-1,numStep+1)
      self.depthFirstSearch(i,j+1,numStep+1)
      self.depthFirstSearch(i+1,j,numStep+1)

      self.visited[(i,j)]=False
```

I genuinely can't see why this won't work but I couldn't pass several hidden test cases for the question.

Also, can anybody tell the runtime of this algorithm? It seems to me like exponential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well DFS isn't a great idea here because you're going to constantly revisit the same sub-paths, and also because you're going to have to explore ALL possible paths to find what's the shortest. Generally speaking when you have a recursive problem with duplication of work going on, you should think about dynamic programming. In this specific case though, you can use DFS, which is in fact pretty similar to what you would do with a standard DP solution for this problem.

Now some notes about your implementation:

- avoid mutation in general, and especially in functional algorithms. It's a bit weird to have a recursive function with side-effects rather than a return value, although it arguably helps reducing the size of the stack.
- I find it quite hard to calculate the complexity. It's basically equal to the number of valid paths of any length, so that's pretty massive in particular when there are few obstacles because there are many paths of length roughly equal to `n*m`.
- I can't find a problem with your logic itself. Are you sure it didn't just time out in the tests that failed?

Comment: I see. Yap that make sense. I suspect it could be that it just time out on large testing input due to the high complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is that you marking the node as unvisited increases unnecessary search, ***It is sure that if the shortest bath between Point A and Dest cannot be longer than the shortest path between B and Dest passing through A***

Use the following

```
class Solution:
   def findShortestDistance(self, maze, start, end):
        self.shortest=math.inf

        #set the default value of visited to be False
        self.visited=defaultdict(lambda: False)

        self.maze=maze
        self.rows=len(maze)
        self.cols=len(maze[0])
        self.depthFirstSearch(0,0,0)
        return self.shortest

   def depthFirstSearch(self, i, j, numStep):
        if i<0 or j<0 or i>=self.rows or j>=self.cols:
            return
        elif self.maze[i][j]=='o':
            return
        elif self.maze[i][j]=='g':
            self.shortest=min(self.shortest,numStep)
            return
        elif self.visited[(i,j)]:
            return

        self.visited[(i,j)] = True
        print("{} {}".format(i,j))
        self.depthFirstSearch(i-1,j,numStep+1)
        self.depthFirstSearch(i,j-1,numStep+1)
        self.depthFirstSearch(i,j+1,numStep+1)
        self.depthFirstSearch(i+1,j,numStep+1)

        return
```

Comment: Not really. Consider this
`
[' s ', '    ', '   ']
[' o ', ' o ', '   ']
[' g ', '    ', '   ']
`
Since the ending point can be anywhere, and the obstacles can be anywhere, we will need to turn be able to go left, or to go above.

Comment: @fzy1995 Thank you for clarifying this point, I understood the problem better now and modified to add the up and left traversal, but marking the node as unvisited makes an unending loop to search, It is sure that if the shortest bath between Point A and Dest cannot be longer than the shortest path between B and Dest passing through A.

Comment: I disagree with your complexity. Some paths can have a length in `O(M*N)`, and there are gazillions of paths (I can't find a formula for counting them right now), so it has to be a lot bigger than `O(N*M)`. I also don't see in which situations the OP's code would result in an infinite loop. Each recursive call has to stop at some point because there's a finite number of valid positions. Since the number of valid positions strictly decreases just after every recursive call and that an end condition is defined for the case when there's no more valid moves, it seems safe to say it will always end

Comment: @Dici Thank you for very well explaining it.

Comment: Np, but don't take my word for it! If you do find an example for which it loops infinitely I'd be interested to see that.